# Text block over image

Tags: html, css

I have used the following tutorial to make a text block over an image: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/. I found it really easy actually, and quite useful, but there is one thing I could never work with, and these are span tags.

The issue I'm having is that I want to format the second part of the text in the span to have a lower font size and have a left padding. I've tried including a second span and defining it in the css file, but it doesn't really do anything, just stays where it is. I also tried extending the block until the end of the picture, but a width of 1000px on each wouldn't work.

Here's some pictures, as they speak a thousand words...

How it looks on mine...

[image]

And how I want it to look...

[image]

And here's some code...

```
<div class="img_destination">

      <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/gsm/images/featured_destination/gcfv.png" alt="" />

      <h2 id="featured_destination"><span>>> Explore Fuerteventura<span class='spacer'></span><span class='spacer'></span>The island of natural beauty</span></h2>

</div>
```

CSS...

```
    /* Featured Destination */

.img_destination {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2#featured_destination {
   position: absolute;
   top: 355px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

h2#featured_destination span {
   color: white;
   font: bold 28px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
   letter-spacing: -1px;
   background: rgba(00, 36, 63, 0.7);
   padding: 10px;
}

h2#featured_destination span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
   background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the effect you're after: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2bETy/)**.

I changed the text div to:

```
<h2 id="featured_destination">
    <span class="bold">>> Explore Fuerteventura</span><span class='spacer'></span><span class='spacer'></span>The island of natural beauty
</h2>
```

I wrapped the first chunk of text in its own span so you can style it with a bold font face while the rest of the text has a normal weight.

And this is the CSS I modified:

```
/* Featured Destination */
.img_destination {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
/* for IE 6 */
}

h2#featured_destination {
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(00,36,63,0.7);
    font: 28px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h2#featured_destination span {
    padding: 10px;
}

h2#featured_destination span.spacer {
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: none;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you posted:

```
<h2 id="featured_destination"><span>>> Explore Fuerteventura<span class='spacer'></span><span class='spacer'></span>The island of natural beauty</span></h2>
```

I would suggest a couple different things. Firstly, instead if using >> for those arrows, use the `&gt;&gt;`. Sometimes extra symbols get rendered incorrectly by the browser, so it is always safest to encode them when you want the display to be literal. Also, I would not use an empty span tag to create whitespace since it tends to clutter up the markup.

But your primary issue is that **you need to change the way your span tags are nested** to NOT include the ">>Explore Fuerteventura" inside any span tags so that the two sections of text are styled differently. I think your aims can be achieved by simply cleaning up your markup to something more like this:

```
<h2 id="featured_destination">&gt;&gt; Explore Fuerteventura <span class='spacer'> The island of natural beauty</span></h2>
```

Comment: That is good idea to. In my answer I also could omit first span (or 'p' after update in jsfiddle code).

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I've included the &gt; now to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="img_destination">
  <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/gsm/images/featured_destination/gcfv.png" alt="" />
  <h2 id="featured_destination">
      <span> &gt; &gt; Explore Fuerteventura
           <span class="smaller">The island of natural beauty</span>
      </span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
h2 > span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 28px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgba(00, 36, 63, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}

h2 span.smaller {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Try that. Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/8PLaB/ Is that what You are looking for?

Your spans .spacer doesn't work because they are empty and browser simply doesn't show them. I think that if You insert in them   then they will do their job but it's not good solution in my opinion. Empty tags never are good solution.

Comment: That works really well, thank you. Can the length of the box be also extended using the span.smaller define?

Comment: Change first span to p. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/8PLaB/1/ Span is inline element, p is block element. I suggest You read about both elements and their differences :) And as @ph33nyx said- instead of >> use &gt;